# spring-aot-maven-plugin failing on mvn clean package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have a project early created and when trying to run `mvn clean package` command, or any other mvn command to build my .jar, the spring AOT plugin is throwing the following error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-aot-maven-plugin:0.9.0:test-generate (test-generate) @ server ---
[ERROR] org.springframework.aot.CodeGenerationException: Could not generate spring.factories source code
```

While researching, I've followed the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#getting-started-buildpacks) and I could not see what's going on on my project that could be causing this error. I even tried to change spring-aot-maven-plugin versions, but it keeps returning the same problem.

If someone knows how to solve this issue, it would be a good help.
Thanks.

Heres my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-native.version>0.9.1</spring-native.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.5.1</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>


  [1]: https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#getting-started-buildpacks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

1. **Remove the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency from the general dependencies section**
2. **Create a profile like**

```
<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

3. **Use the `local`-profile for running only:** `mvn -Plocal spring-boot:run` or make it the default by adding the following to the profile section

```
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```